# Problemas para agregar node api a MySQL Cluster con Docker

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

Alguien me puede ayudar ya tengo levantado el cluster de mysql con docker, pero solo me deja agregar un nodo api cuando intento agregar uno nuevo con:

```
docker run -d --net=cluster --name=mysql2 --ip=192.X.X.X -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysqld
```

Por alguna razón al principio si levanta el servicio docker, pero luego para la ejecución del mismo y por lo que cuando ingreso al manager para revisar mis nodos no tengo este nuevo que recien agrege.

Necesito ayuda si alguien le sucedió esto como lo resolvio.[image: Terminal del manager para ver los nodos del cluster]

Comment: Intente ejecutar: `docker run -d --net=cluster --name=mysql2 --ip=192.X.X.X -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true mysql/mysql-cluster mysqld`.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario ya lo intente de esa manera y no me funciono.